# Getting second last record from firestore DB, javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

As firestore is not that much old yet, there is very small help out there in some scenarios.

I am trying to get 2nd last record from **Firestore** but it's getting very first one. i know it's wrong query:

```
db.collection("batches")
  .where('added_at', "<", paymentData.added_at) //Here paymentData is last record
  .limit(1).get().then(function(prevSnapshot){
})
```

For example i have 3 records

```
A. added_at: 1 Jan, 2017
B. added_at: 2 Jan, 2017
C. added_at: 3 Jan, 2017
```

And i have `C` in paymentData right now and i want record `B`. But it's getting record `A`.

How do i get **Second Last Record** ?

**EDIT:**

Each record will always have newer timestamp than previous one (even it can be 1 Minute. e.g previous `27 Jan, 2017 5:20 PM` and new `27 Jan, 2017 5:21 PM`)

And paymentData will always have **latest record**.

Basically i want to compare two values of **current payment** and **previous payment** and display it's difference to user.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The order of Firestore documents is not guaranteed, unless you specifically [order the documents in your query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data). To do this, you'll need to use the `orderBy()` method.

For example, you can specify that the database sorts your documents by the `added_at` field in descending order, which should return your desired result, `B`:

```
db.collection("batches")
  .orderBy('added_at', 'desc') // Order documents by added_at field in descending order
  .where('added_at', "<", paymentData.added_at)
  .limit(1).get().then(function(prevSnapshot){
          // ...
  })
```

Be careful though: multiple documents with the same timestamp, or timestamps in between the one you're expecting, may mean that you'll receive a different document than expected, so I wouldn't rely on this to pick specific documents.

Comment: Nop Sir, it's giving me the document `A`. `A's` `added_at` is `October 21, 2017 at 12:13:17 PM` and `B's` added_at is `October 21, 2017 at 12:11:54 PM` and `C's` added_at is `October 21, 2017 at 12:09:42 PM`

Comment: But they have nested childs too with `timestamps`, is that making problem?

Comment: The order in your comment is the reverse to that of your question, so you'll need to change the sort order to `.orderBy('added_at', 'asc')` instead. Also, the nested child's timestamp won't matter here because the ordering is based solely on the `added_at` field.

Comment: If i reverse it, it will get `C`. Even if i have 10 documents, i want to get second last.

Comment: There is no automatic ordering so getting the "second last" will only be possible once you have ordered them correctly (using `orderBy()`). Do you want the newest record last or the oldest record last? And will `paymentData` always have a newer timestamp than existing data in the list? Can you clarify this in your question?

Comment: Yes, please see EDIT part of my question. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks, I've tested the example in this answer and it is working OK for me when the documents are sorted using `orderBy('added_at', 'desc')` and `where('added_at', '<', paymentData.added_at)` is using the `added_at` date of the most recent document in the database. Are you sure that `paymentData` has been saved to the database before you call the above?

Comment: Yes, okay i will try it once more and get back. Thanks for your time, really appreciate that.